# Replacing a char in a string

Tags: string, char, stringbuilder

I am trying to replace "2" with "C".

```
String numbers = "99929";
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(numbers);
temp.setCharAt(3, "C");
```

I am getting an error stating

> I ncompatible type, String cannot be converted to Char.

What does this mean? Sorry im new to this. Appreciate your kind help!

Comment: What language are you using? Please edit your tags to include the proper language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"C" (double quoted literal) is a String in Java but setCharAt accepts a char as the second parameter, try 'C' instead which is a char literal:

```
temp.setCharAt(3, 'C');
```

Answer (score 0):

A `String` value can't be assigned to a char, they are different types, apples and oranges

```
String numbers = "99929";
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(numbers);
temp.setCharAt(3, 'C'); // THIS LINE IS EDITED
```

As you can see I edit last line of your code, I replaced double quotes with single quotes, because they don't have same meaning, actually
***use single quotes for literal `chars`, double quotes for literal `Strings`.***

Comment: Hi ! thankyou so much! the single quotes solved the issue! thankyou!!